# HttpClient retry handler on response 429

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, httpclient

When the remote server returns a 429 (Too Many Requests) response with the `Retry-After` header, the HttpClient can handle such cases with a handler:

```
public class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests
            && response.Headers.RetryAfter is not null)
        {
            var delta = TimeSpan.Zero;
            if (response.Headers.RetryAfter.Date.HasValue)
            {
                delta = response.Headers.RetryAfter.Date.Value - DateTimeOffset.Now;
            }

            if (delta <= TimeSpan.Zero && response.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta.HasValue)
            {
                delta = response.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta.Value;
            }

            if (delta > TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                await Task.Delay(delta, cancellationToken);

                response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

And usage example:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new RetryHandler(), new Handler2(), new Handler3());
```

Do you see any improvements / problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me suggest here an alternative solution, namely the [Polly's retry policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry). This library is the [Microsoft suggested way to decorate any `HttpClient`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) (normal, named, typed or named and typed clients).

In order to use it, you need the following libraries:

- [Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly): this helps you to define policies
- [Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly): this helps you to integrate policies into the `HttpClient`'s pipeline

  - Please be aware that there is a *Polly.Extensions.Http* package as well but that is **deprecated**

#### The policy

In order to define a retry policy against `HttpClient` you need to do the followings:

- Define a policy which returns with an `HttpResponseMessage`
- Define that policy as asynchronous

So, the defined policy must be an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`:

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryAfterPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests && r.Headers.RetryAfter != null)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
      1,
      (_, result, _) => result.Result.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta.Value,
      (_, __, ___, ____) => Task.CompletedTask);
```

OR

```
Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool> shouldRetry = r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests && r.Headers.RetryAfter != null;
var retryAfterPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult(shouldRetry)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
      1,
      (_, result, _) => result.Result.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta.Value,
      (_, __, ___, ____) => Task.CompletedTask);
```

The parameters of the `WaitAndRetryAsync`

- `retryCount`: How many retries should be issued if the condition is met (the predicate provided to the `HandleResult`)
- `sleepDurationProvider`: How much time should be spent with sleeping/waiting between retry attempts
- `onRetryAsync`: This delegate is designed mainly for logging purposes. It is called before the policy goes to sleep between two retry attempts

#### The integration

The Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly defines several extension methods:

- [`AddPolicyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1): It allows you to decorate an `HttpClient` with an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` policy
- [`AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandlerfromregistry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1): Polly allows us to add our policies to a [registry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry). This method allows you to decorate an `HttpClient` with an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` policy from a pre-populated registry
- [`AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addtransienthttperrorpolicy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1): It allows you to decorate an `HttpClient` with an `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>` policy. It is pre-configured to trigger for `HttpRequestException` and for status code: 408 or 5xx

[Under the hood all of them register](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/DependencyInjection/PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs) a [`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.policyhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) into the `HttpClient` pipeline which is indeed a `DelegatingHandler`.

Let me show you how to use it for a named client

```
builder.Services
.AddHttpClient("SampleApi", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://.../");
})
.AddPolicyHandler(retryAfterPolicy);
```

Usage

```
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    public SampleController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SampleApi");
        //...
    }
}
```

#### Next steps

If you have received a 429 that means the downstream system is overloaded / under pressure / flooded with requests. So, it might make sense to let it perform self-healing and then retry any pending requests.

With the above setup each and every concurrent requests are sent to the downstream system to receive the same `"I'm busy"` response. It would be nice if we could avoid this unnecessary roundtrips to get the same message.

The good news is that we can do this by using a [Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker). This can be used to short cut any outgoing requests while the downstream is trying to heal itself. [The CB has a shared state](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Statefulness-of-policies) which can be accessed by the concurrent requests. So, rather than flooding the downstream with new requests we can prevent that on the client-side by short-cutting them.

We can [combine the retry policy with circuit breaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024445/polly-contrib-waitandretry-to-funnel-all-requests-when-hitting-rate-limit/73055228#73055228) to define a protocol which will respect the `RetryAfter` header and applies that to all outgoing requests.

---

I would like to mention one other policy which might be useful here and that is the [timeout policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout). It allows you to define an upper limit on time to get a valuable response.

Either you can define that time constraint on a per retry attempt bases

```
retry > local_timeout
```

Or you can define that time constraint as an overarching constraint which covers all retry attempts

```
global_timeout > retry
```

Or you can combine both

```
global_timeout (60 seconds) > retry (three times) > local_timeout (2 seconds)
```

And of course the Circuit Breaker could be added to this [policy chain](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) as well. I have posted a lots of answers on SO about this topic, just to name a few: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473924/cannot-make-polly-timeout-policy-override-the-httpclient-default-timeout/63563229#63563229), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405901/polly-retry-pass-all-execution-until-a-retry-is-successful/70410434#70410434), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120902/catching-the-last-exception-in-polly-in-net-core/67127817#67127817), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806212/httpclient-polly-waitandretry-policy/62832357#62832357), etc.